# How to make background transparent and change my activity Design

Tags: android

I have created a login activity below is the screen shot and code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpZU4.png)

code is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="pk.itbrowser.rehbar.LoginActivity"
android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20sp">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Login with Email"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="Email"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Login"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:text="Need an Account?"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Forget Password?"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now i want to change this activity to like below one
light black background for editText simply want to build such design
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTv7D.png)

Comment: what is a problem then?

Comment: use a framelayout

Comment: Set ARGB color code (#10000000) as background.

Comment: set transparent theme of your activity

Answer (score 0):

1. Set `transparent-black`(`#D8000000`) background color to your container `RelativeLayout`
2. Set `dark-grey`(`#3F4045`) background color to your `EditText's`

**Try this:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="pk.itbrowser.rehbar.LoginActivity"
android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
android:background="#D8000000"> <!-- Transparent-Black -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Login with Email"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#3F4045"
        android:hint="Email"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#3F4045"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Login"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:text="Need an Account?"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Forget Password?"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Help me to create a transparent activity

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare transparent theme for the Activity in Manifest

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

and set background of your layout to transparent black

```
android:background="#44000000"
```